# Pattern for vertical motion using technic lego

Tags: technic, motor

I have a motor and some other components that move a machine vertical on the ground. Inside the machine i need to raise a part by 5 cm, up and down.

Are there some common patterns that can move objects vertically (lift) using technic lego? Torque comes from a motor powering gears.

Comment: It seems from your question that you want to convert a continuous circular motion from the motor into an up and down motion with a range of 5cm - is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You can use a mechanism like this:

[image: Piston]

This is a mechanism that converts circular motion into [reciprocating motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocating_motion). You may need to alter the design for your needs regarding height difference, stability etc.

Answer (score 6):

You can accomplish this using gear racks (3743):

[image]

You just have to create some type of channel that allows the rack to slide vertically, and then set up a gear to mesh with the rack. You can do this however you like, but here's a quick example that I built to show you what I mean:

[image]

Comment: if only the gear racks weren't so hard to come across!

Comment: Indeed. They're fairly affordable on Bricklink, though: http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?colorID=86&itemID=697

Comment: The gear racks were quite common on the early Technic cars with steering.